# Difference between connect() and connect_after() in pygtk

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I don't know what are Differences between `connect()` and `connect_after()` in pygtk.  can someone explain this with an example code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, here is the definition for [`g_signal_connect_after`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect-after):

> Connects a GCallback function to a signal for a particular object.The
>   handler will be called **after the default handler of the signal**.

But what is the default handler you may ask, well, the [GSignal description](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html) it's very descritive:

> The basic concept of the signal system is that of the emission of a
>   signal. Signals are introduced per-type and are identified through
>   strings. Signals introduced for a parent type are available in derived
>   types as well, so basically they are a per-type facility that is
>   inherited.
>
> A signal emission mainly involves invocation of a certain set of
>   callbacks in precisely defined manner. There are two main categories
>   of such callbacks, per-object ones and user provided ones. (Although
>   signals can deal with any kind of instantiatable type, I'm referring
>   to those types as "object types" in the following, simply because that
>   is the context most users will encounter signals in.) The per-object
>   callbacks are most often referred to as "object method handler" or
>   "default (signal) handler", while user provided callbacks are usually
>   just called "signal handler".
>
> The object method handler is provided at signal creation time (this
>   most frequently happens at the end of an object class' creation),
>   while user provided handlers are frequently connected and disconnected
>   to/from a certain signal on certain object instances.
>
> A signal emission consists of five stages, unless prematurely stopped:
>
> - Invocation of the object method handler for G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST signals
> - Invocation of normal user-provided signal handlers (where the after flag is not set)
> - Invocation of the object method handler for G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST signals
> - Invocation of user provided signal handlers (where the after flag is set)
> - Invocation of the object method handler for G_SIGNAL_RUN_CLEANUP signals
>
> **The user-provided signal handlers are called in the order they were connected in.**

Now that you know the signal sequence, what follows is the [answer to a similar question](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2006-January/msg00100.html) but on the Gtk mailing list:

> g_signal_connect_after will let you run your user handler after the
>   class's default handler; why is this usefull ?
>
> Say I have an object that emits an "initialize" signal in which its
>   class handler does the work, you probably want your handler to run
>   after the class handler so that you can use the already initialized
>   object in your function.
>
> I think normally you dont have to use this method because signals of
>   that nature are usually installed with G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST which; if
>   I'm not mistaken means that it's default handler will be called before
>   user handlers anyway.

Using it on higher level languages may not have an obvious need but, eg., lets say that you want to guarantee that a callback will be the last user callback to run, then you can use this method. (Note pygtk is deprecated, use pygobject).

A simple example where we connect two methods, `on_click2` and `on_click1` (by this order), by using `connect_after` for `on_click2` we make sure that it will run last (user callbacks):

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Button(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self, message):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self, spacing=6)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label(message)
        self.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)
        button.connect_after("clicked", self.on_click2)
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click1)

    def on_click1(self, widget):
        print ("Click1 signal. connect normal");

    def on_click2(self, widget):
        print ("Click2 signal. connect after");

win = Gtk.Window()
button = Button("Test")

win.add (button)

win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

And the result is that `on_click2` is the last to be called despite the fact it was the first connected:

```
$ python <filename.py>
... (Click test button)...
Click1 signal. connect normal
Click2 signal. connect after
```

[image]